# I do not understand why this code won't work(new to JRadioButtons)

Tags: java, jradiobutton

I am learning `JRadioButtons` and I do not know why it is working in the tutorial I am watching and not in my code. Could someone please take a look at it?

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        screen.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Here is the Screen Class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Screen extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JRadioButton b1, b2;
    ButtonGroup group;
    JTextArea tb;

    public Screen(){
        super("First GUI");
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

        JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("Text Area");

        group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(b1);
        group.add(b2);

        b1 = new JRadioButton("Hello");
        b1.setActionCommand("HELLO!");
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        b2 = new JRadioButton("Goodbye");
        b2.setActionCommand("Goodbye! =)");
        b2.addActionListener(this);

        p1.add(b1);
        p1.add(b2);
        p1.add(tb);

        add(p1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tb.setText(e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

In my new Java head this should work perfectly. I initialize the buttons, initialize the group. I am getting an error after I click one of the buttons: `AWT-EventQueue-0`. I do not know what that means so I do not know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Try instantiating the radio buttons before adding them to the group.

Comment: That is not an issue but thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Please improve your question titles. There supposed to be informative, to summarize your *problem* not your *plight*. Assume that your code is not decent to begin with for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared twice the same variable. If you declare the same variable (`JTextArea tb`) in the global and local scope, it will be a separate object. Remove the declaration in the local scope from the `Screen()` constructor so it will work.
Try this

```
tb = new JTextArea("Text Area");
```

instead of

```
JTextArea tb = new JTextArea("Text Area");
```

Because of your current code, `tb` is still not initialized in the global scope.